# Schwinger's oscillator model for angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

Schwinger's angular momentum ladder operators are defined as

$J_{+} = a^{\dagger}_{+}a_{-}$,  $J_{-} = a_{+}a_{-}^{\dagger}$ and $J_{z} = a^{\dagger}_{+}a_{+}-a^{\dagger}_{-}a_{-}$.  I am wondering is it possible to write $a^{\dagger}_{+}a^{\dagger}_{-}$ and $a_{+}a_{-}$ in terms of angular momentum operators in the Schwinger's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not.  The angular momentum operators as defined are necessarily number-preserving operators so that any function of them will also be number preserving.

Operators like $a_+a_-$ etc are actually generators of $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)\sim \mathfrak{sp}(2,\mathbb{R})$.  There is a nice tutorial in this in

> Novaes, Marcel. "Some basics of su (1, 1)." Revista Brasileira de Ensino de Fisica 26.4 (2004): 351-357.

The article is open access, and the realization you are looking for is given in Eq.(32).